# QTKit QTMovie::insertSegmentOfTrack not working on OS X 10.7 or 10.8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audio, quicktime, qtkit

I have a class written using `QTKit` that reads and creates `QuickTime` movie files. My function to add an audio track to a movie, which works just fine on Snow Leopard, does not work on Lion or Mountain Lion. The audio information does appear in "Show Movie Inspector" in the `QuickTime` Player, and the movie is the correct duration. However, the audio is inaudible upon movie playback. Here is my code that works great in 10.6, but not 10.7 or 10.8:

```
// here's the code that creates the exported movie
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Foo.mov"];
NSError *errorPtr;
qtMovie = [[QTMovie alloc] initToWritableFile:filePath error:&errorPtr];

// and now here is my function to add an audio track
bool PLQTMovie::addSoundTrack(const std::string &fileName, const long long srcStartTime, const long long srcEndTime, const long long dstStartTime)
{
  NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSString *file = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:fileName.c_str()];
  NSError *errorPtr = nil;
  QTMovie *audioMovie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:file error:&errorPtr];

  NSArray *tracks = [audioMovie tracksOfMediaType:QTMediaTypeSound];
  if([tracks count] == 0)
    return false;

  QTTrack *soundTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
  QTMedia *media = [soundTrack media];
  NSValue *durationValue = [media attributeForKey:QTMediaDurationAttribute];
  QTTime soundTrackTime;
  [durationValue getValue:&soundTrackTime];
  long audioScale = soundTrackTime.timeScale;

  long long srcDuration = 0;
  if(srcEndTime < 0) // use entire source track duration
  {
    srcDuration = soundTrackTime.timeValue;
  }
  else
  {
    srcDuration = srcEndTime - srcStartTime;
  }

  QTTime startTime = QTMakeTime(srcStartTime, audioScale);
  QTTime srcDurationTime = QTMakeTime(srcDuration, audioScale);
  QTTimeRange srcTimeRange = QTMakeTimeRange(startTime, srcDurationTime);
  QTTime dstTime = QTMakeTime(dstStartTime, audioScale);

  QTTrack *audioTrack = [(QTMovie*)qtMovie insertSegmentOfTrack:soundTrack timeRange:srcTimeRange atTime:dstTime];

  [pool drain];

  return true;
}
```

I know that Apple encourages transitioning from `QTKit` to `AV Foundation`, but the old `QTKit` code should still work. I'm at a loss as to what I should be doing differently here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will help, but we had a similar problem and the answer turned out to be that you need to flatten the movie after adding the audio.

Basically, we had to write the movie to a tmp file, then export that with [`QTMovie writeToFile:withAttributes:error]` with an attribute of QTMovieFlatten set to YES.

Hope this helps, so I can start to pay back some of the great tips/answers I've gotten here.